# 2011 MacBook Pro left Command + V not working

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I have an early 2011 mackbook pro the left command + v paste isn't working left command v works as does left commad x etc but I can only paste with right commad v which is driving me nuts and slowing up my workflow!!

I have tried renaming keyboard...plist and systemprefs..plist and usersomethingorother.plist I have tried a pram reset and command option shift power button then restart but non of this works?

Comment: Does it work if you use an external keyboard?

Comment: not got one to try it

Comment: If you can borrow one then it may help you figure out if it was a hardware or software issue...

Comment: I have just copied and pasted some text using left command v in my browser  ````I have just copied and pasted some text```` and in textpad !! but it seems to work for a while after I do it in the browser on other apps but then reverts back very strange